# search in the list of strings in python

Tags: python

I want to search countries from my list here is my list:

```
 country=['American Samoa',
 'Andorra','Angola','Anguilla'
 ,'Antarctica',' Barbuda',
 'Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Aruba',
 'Australia',
 'Austria','Azerbaijan’,'Bahamas','Bangladesh','Barbados','BELARUS']
```

I have used this function but I think it's wrong

```
def find(f,seq):
    for item in country:
        if f(item):
            return item
```

Can you please correct my codes
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? Why do you pass `seq` to it if you don't use it? You probably just have to exchange `country` for `seq`. Also it would be nice to know what `f` is doing.

Comment: Because I'm not getting the result,I'm beginner in python and so confuse about this language.I thought f is a counter and that will return the first item in a sequence

Comment: The name of a variable never has any special meaning in Python, or in pretty much any other programming language I can think of. The purpose of a variable is the purpose that you give it. 'f' is whatever you pass to the function in that spot.

Answer (score 5):

Hm, here's a stab which is perhaps a bit more clear:

```
def country_found(country_to_find):
    countries=['American Samoa','Andorra','Angola','Anguilla','Antarctica',
    'Barbuda','Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Aruba','Australia', 'Austria','Azerbaijan’,
    'Bahamas','Bangladesh','Barbados','BELARUS']

    return (country_to_find in countries)
```

Then you can just say "if country_found('Armenia'):" or whatever.

Comment: just "return country_to_find in countries", no need for the if/else at the end.

Comment: It doesn't give me the string it gives me boolean value

Comment: I just want to search a counry from the list

Comment: @mary If you have a country, this function will return True if the country is found and False if it's not. Or, you could return country_to_find if country_to_find in countries if you want the actual string back for some reason.

Comment: Upvoted only because saw `"if country_found('Armenia'):"` - i'm Armenian :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just use

```
countries = ['American Samoa', ...]
if country in countries:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

```
filter(f,seq)
```

That's all.

And if you don't know what is **f** , it's a pity but we can't guess it.

See also `iflter()`

And search in the docs with this idea in mind when you need to do something rather generic: "there MUST be some function that does what I want, WHERE is it ?" .

Instead of "HOW to do that ?".

Comment: @mary And then !!!? Am I supposed to be surprised by this result ? On what basis should I be surprised ? I don't know what you want to obtain and what **f** is. DO you UNDERSTAND that WE CAN'T GUESS what **f** is , while the result will depend on **f** ? Instead of tripling the exclamation points, you should answer to the question that Felix Kling asked you 2 hours ago _"You should explain what exactly you want do to..."_

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer. The logic is basic. If item is in list, it also has an index. And accessing the element with this index (`list[index]`) will return verily this item :)

```
def find_country(country):
    try:
        i = countries.index(country)
        res = countries[res]
    except:
        res = "No such country"

    return res



$ python find_country.py 
Azerbaijan
Angola
No such country
```